# Why does my Tkinter window close after the while loop, even though I have an update and a quit before hand?

Tags: python, sockets, tkinter

I am trying to make an application that connects two people in python using both the socket and tkinter libraries. At the moment I am having problem getting the tkinter window to disappear like I want (My next steps will be having a new window appear for two people to perhaps chat in?

Right now I have the following snippet. I don't think I should need the update, because this is all in a thread while mainloop is in main. but it doesn't work with or without it. The tkinter will start to freeze while I am in the while loop of the socket connection, but I am not worried about fixing that at the moment I don't think.

Edit, adding more code to show my minimum amount of code. This is the least I could get to, before the socket or tkinter seemed to stop working all together

main Function:

```
from tkinter import *
import threading
from hosting import getHostAddress, getConnected
from client import connectToHost
 
def hostServer():
    hostB.destroy()
    connectB.destroy()
    e.destroy()

    addr, sock = getHostAddress()
    hostingText = addr + "\nWaiting for Connection"

    hostLabel = Label(window, text=hostingText)
    hostLabel.pack()

    getConnected(sock, window)

def connectToIP():
    IP = e.get()
    window.destroy()
    connectToHost(IP)

def connectServer():
    hostB.destroy()
    connectB.destroy()

    conLabel = Label(window, text="Enter Code")
    conLabel.pack(side="left")
    e.pack(side="left")
    window.geometry("250x50")
    conButton = Button(window, text="Connect", command=connectToIP)
    conButton.pack(side="left")

if __name__ =="__main__":
    window = Tk()
    
    e = Entry(window)
    hostB = Button(window, text="Host", command=threading.Thread(target=hostServer).start)
    hostB.pack()
    connectB = Button(window, text="Connect", command=connectServer)
    connectB.pack()

    window.mainloop()
```

client.py

```
import socket

port = 5000;
client = socket.socket()

def connectToHost(IPAddr):
  client.connect((IPAddr, port))

  message = input(" -> ")  # take input

  while message.lower().strip() != 'bye':
    client.send(message.encode())  # send message
    data = client.recv(1024).decode()  # receive response

    print('Received from server: ' + data)  # show in terminal

    message = input(" -> ")  # again take input

  client.close()  # close the connection
```

hosting.py

```
import socket

#def getPort():

def getHostAddress():
  hostname = socket.gethostname()
  IPAddr = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)

  sock = socket.socket()
  sock.bind((hostname, 5000))

  addr = IPAddr

  return addr, sock

def getConnected(sock, window):
  sock.listen(2)
  conn, address = sock.accept()  # accept new connection

  window.quit()
  window.update()

  while True:
    # receive data stream. it won't accept data packet greater than 1024 bytes
    data = conn.recv(1024).decode()
    if not data:
      # if data is not received break
      break
    print("from connected user: " + str(data))
    data = input(' -> ')
    conn.send(data.encode())  # send data to the client

  conn.close()  # close the connection
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide a complete [mcve]. We need to see how you're running this in a thread.

Comment: side note:  standard indentation = 4 spaces.

Comment: `window.quit()` just terminates `mainloop()`, but not destroy the window. Use `window.destroy()` instead.

Comment: using window.destroy() seems to exit the socket all together which terminates the connection

Comment: For your case, I don't think you need to run `hostServer()` in a thread.  Also I don't think you need the GUI at all because the final chat while loop is using console input.

Comment: right now I am just trying to test the connection via gui, before eventually making the gui go further